# How can a message client read an attachment downloaded by indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I have a message client, written in delphi using Indy libraries, that receives email messages. I am having difficulties decoding an MMS text message email.

These messages come as `multipart/mixed` emails with one message part (an attachment) that of `text/plain` (that is base64 encoded) with a filename like `text0.txt`.

My TIdMessageClient calls ProcessMessage (using the stream-based version) to populate a TidMessage that I'm going to display on the screen. But as I go through the message parts and try to unravel them, that attached file is a thorn in my side. Currently, I have it printing out the name of the attachment into a string which works fine (see code snippet below, FBody is a string type), but can't get the text file's contents.

Here's the bit that does work:

```
FBody := 'Attachment: ['+TidAttachment(Msg.MessageParts.Items[0]).FileName+']';
```

(Edited:) Originally when I wrote this question I wasn't sure if the attachment was stored in a TidAttachmentFile or TidAttachmentMemory object. But with the right debugger commands, I've determined it's a TidAttachmentFile. I suppose it would be possible to use TidAttachmentFile.SaveToFile() to save the attachment to a file on disk and then read the file back from disk, but that seems wasteful and slow (especially for a 200 character text message).  I would really prefer to do this all "in memory" without temp files if possible.

What do I need to do (a) make TidMessageClient return a TidAttachmentMemory object rather than a TidAttachmentObject (in ProcessMessage), and (b) read the attached text file into a string?

Based on the indy documentation, the start I have at how this code would look is roughly like this:

```
TidAttachmentMemory(Msg.MessageParts.Items[0]).PrepareTempStream();
FBody := FBody + TidAttachmentMemory(Msg.MessageParts.Items[0]).DataString;
TidAttachmentMemory(Msg.MessageParts.Items[0]).FinishTempStream;
```

Please feel free to point me in the right direction if this is not the right way to go or use TidAttachment(s).

Comment: You can discover the type of object by calling `ClassName` on it. Inspecting the object in the debugger would probably work, too.

Comment: The starter edition of Delphi has rather crippled object inspection capabilities--it doesn't include most of the object visualizers in the professional editions. I've tried to figure out what type the object is through the debugger, but so far have been unsuccessful. I'll give ClassName a try though :)

Comment: Looks like `Msg.MessageParts.Items[0].classtype` is a TIdAttachmentFile. Thanks for the pointer on where to start looking for determining the class type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose it would be possible to use TidAttachmentFile.SaveToFile() to save the attachment to a file on disk and then read the file back from disk, but that seems wasteful and slow (especially for a 200 character text message).

When using `TIdAttachmentFile`, the file is always on disk.  The `TIdAttachmentFile.StoredPathName` property specifies the path to the actual file.  The `TIdAttachmentFile.SaveToFile()` method merely copies the file to the specified location.

> I would really prefer to do this all "in memory" without temp files if possible.

It is possible.

> What do I need to do (a) make TidMessageClient return a TidAttachmentMemory object rather than a TidAttachmentObject (in ProcessMessage)

In the `TIdMessage.OnCreateAttachment` event, return a `TIdAttachmentMemory` object, eg:

```
procedure TMyForm.IdMessage1CreateAttachment(const AMsg: TIdMessage; const AHeaders: TStrings; var AAttachment: TIdAttachment);
begin
  AAttachment := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(AMsg.MessageParts);
end;
```

If no handler is assigned to the `TIdMessage.OnCreateAttachment` event, or if it does not assign anything to `AAttachment`, then a `TIdAttachmentFile` is created by default.

You could optionally implement your own custom `TIdAttachment`-derived class instead, say one that uses `TStringStream` internally if you know the attachment contains textual data (which the `AHeaders` parameter will tell you).

> and (b) read the attached text file into a string?
>
> Based on the indy documentation, the start I have at how this code would look is roughly like this:

You are close.  You need to use the `TIdAttachment.OpenLoadStream()` method instead of `TIdAttachment.PrepareTempStream()`, and you need to read the data from the `TStream` that `TIdAttachment.OpenLoadStream()` returns.  In your example, you could use Indy's `ReadStringFromStream()` function for that, eg:

```
// if using Indy 10.6 or later...
var
  Attachment: TIdAttachment;
  Strm: TStream;
 begin
  ...
  Attachment := TIdAttachment(Msg.MessageParts.Items[0]);
  Strm := Attachment.OpenLoadStream;
  try
    FBody := FBody + ReadStringFromStream(Strm, -1, CharsetToEncoding(Attachment.Charset));
  finally
    Attachment.CloseLoadStream;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Or:

```
// if using Indy 10.5.x or earlier...
var
  Attachment: TIdAttachment;
  Strm: TStream;
  Enc: TIdTextEncoding;
 begin
  ...
  Attachment := TIdAttachment(Msg.MessageParts.Items[0]);
  Strm := Attachment.OpenLoadStream;
  try
    Enc := CharsetToEncoding(Attachment.Charset);
    try
      FBody := FBody + ReadStringFromStream(Strm, -1, Enc);
    finally
      Enc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Attachment.CloseLoadStream;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Remy, I get a compile error (no overloaded version of create with those args) trying to use your example for creating a TIdAttachmentMemory. It appears there is no longer a default constructor for TIdAttachmentMemory? there is a comment in the source code for that class "    {CC: Bug fix, remove default values to resolve ambiguities with Create(TCollection).}" so it appears intentional, but I can't figure out how to fix that compile error. none of the other constructors seem to fit with the args I have there.

Comment: after some googling, it appears perhaps it should be `AAttachment := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(AMsg.MessageParts);`?

Comment: Yes, it should be that.  I have fixed the example.